# plotting the energy of an ion as a function of its (x,y,z) coordinates

Tags: graphing-functions

Very basic question but I am struggling to get my head around it as it seems to me that I am trying to plot 4 variables ...

Is it possible to visualize the variation of a quantity, given that it is a (unknown) function of 3 variables, on one plot? [Essentially the data I have is the coordinates of an ion in 3d space and its energy at that point].

Comment: I would draw level surfaces or even level curves on slices... But I don't know if there is a standard _best_ way to do it.

Comment: I agree with @Duronman. Drawing the level surfaces makes you feeling of plotting it in the $4$ dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that it is indeed possible. The following link shows some ways of visualization for a Cosmic Ray (CR) problem in astronomy:

[CR pressure with AVS](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/zonwind/zonavs.htm)

AVS = "Advanced Visualization System" (: let Google be your friend). I don't know if  meanwhile there are cheap (i.e. non-commercial) alternatives for the latter.
One method is to plot the energy of the ions as colored dots. Example:

[image]